# Display: inline-block issues

Tags: html, css

i am using display:inner-block in my code. But inline-block automatically assigns padding between divs's which is causing browser incompatibility in my site. Can any one point out a solution.

Here a fiddle for basic reference.Here you can clearly see the padding assigned by inner block property

http://jsfiddle.net/damsarabi/vbhnF/#&togetherjs=4aiQ9gSCpq

This is the basic code for reference in fiddle

```
<div class="LabelColumn">label column</div>
<div class="DataColumn">data column</div>


div{
 border:1px solid #000   
}

div.LabelColumn
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**inline-block** doesn't automatically add margin, it is inline, which means it takes notice of your white space between each element. Even though this might look like a 4px or so margin, it's not, it's a single space. One way to get round it would be to remove the whitespace:

```
<div class = "LabelColumn">asdfasdf</div><div class = "LabelColumn">asdfasdf</div><div class = "DataColumn">data</div><div class = "LabelColumn">asdfasdf</div><div class = "DataColumn">data</div><div class = "LabelColumn">asdfasdf</div><div class = "DataColumn">data</div>
```

Another, to comment out the whitespace:

```
<div class = "LabelColumn">asdfasdf</div><!--
--><div class = "LabelColumn">asdfasdf</div>
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/vbhnF/74/)

Or lastly, but by no means least, `float:left` instead of changing the `display` type:

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/vbhnF/75/)

Comment: I had read about this. Man how can i forget. Wasted 5 hours with this. Thanks Mate

Answer (score 2):

By default, there is an extra margin-right of 4px (according to the font-size parent).

You can fix this issue with a css tweak. It's the solution I use more often, and it's easy way to adjust this alignment.

```
div.LabelColumn
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

You can see more tweaks on this link : http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I recommend reading mentioned CSS-Tricks article - I've read it too and it is very helpful. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can set `font-size` of container to `0` and set necessary `font-size` for floating elements. This will eliminate spaces.
This is useful for cases when you can't avoid white-spaces between your elements (for example, some IDEs can be configured to automatically reformat markup).

```
div.LabelColumn
{
    font-size:16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.full_width {
   width:100%;
   font-size:0;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/htAR6/2/

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
<div class="LabelColumn">label column</div>
<div class="DataColumn">data column</div>

div.LabelColumn
{
    font-size:16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.full_width {
   width:100%;
   font-size:0;
}
```